# Set mouse scroll as shortcut for just one application?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, mouse-scroll

I'm using Unity in Ubuntu 14.04, but since I can't put the Unity dock on the bottom of the screen, I've set it to hide and set the sensitivity low enough that my mouse can't activate it and slide it out. In place of the Unity dock, I now use the Cairo-Dock, but the Cairo-Dock changes apps if the scroll wheel is bumped.

There's no way that I can find to disable the scroll wheel app switching, so I'd like to know if there is a way to bind the scroll wheel to a system shortcut only when the mouse is over the Cairo-Dock.

I've already bound ctrl + scroll-wheel to /bin/true system wide to disable zooming in every app using .xbindkeysrc, but I don't know if there's a way to set things like this up on a per application basis.

Does anyone know definitively if this is possible?